# Encrypting columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I need to encrypt several columns in a database.

Do I create one certificate and a symmetric key for each column or one certificate and one symmetric key per column.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the data coming from? If you have an application, especially a web based application you should encrypt the data prior to transmitting it.

Comment: The data comes from a database and will be used to configure a connection strings. I want to encrypt passwords in the database and was wondering what the best practice is for implementing column level encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using SQL Server's [Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx)?

Comment: I have but isn't TDE for data "at rest" e.g. encryption of data, log, and backup files?

Comment: I didn't see in your original post were you referred the Data, Log and Backup files.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with MS SQL 2008 cell level encryption, you need to set up a master key for your database, create a certificate for your database, and based on that certificate a symmetric key that you will use to encrypt cell level data.

Columns for which you want to encrypt the data on have to be of one of type VARBINARY (or two others: I believe VARCHAR, and NVARCHAR, but I'm not certain). There is also a specific method of inserting/updating data in these columns, as well as reading data from these columns.

We're currently storing a few selected columns of sensitive information encrypted in this manner in VARBINARY(256) columns, along with TDE on top of our database.

More information and helpful tutorials can be found here:

http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/articles/sql-server-bi/19/cell-level-encryption-in-sql-server
http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2005/11/24/415079.aspx